# Deleting elements from list depending on randomly generated number

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, random

This function should take a list of viruses like [ATCG, GTAC.....] and a mortalityProb (float between 0 and 1) that represents the chance of a virus to die / get deleted from the list.  It should return a new list with the remaining viruses. Each of the viruses has an individual chance to die, so with a mortalityProb of say 0.6, there should be around 60% of the viruses remaining.

It should be doable in 2 lines (including def kill(viruses, mortalityProb):) and my line of code using list comprehensions.

```
def kill(viruses, mortalityProb):
    for i in viruses:
        if random.randint(0, 100) < (mortalityProb * 100):
            del i
    return viruses
```

This does not quite work, but I can't get a grasp on why.

Comment: `del i` means "unassign the `i` variable". It does nothing more than that; it will not remove any objects from any lists.

Comment: One way to do this is `viruses.remove(i)`.  However, see the various postings on altering a list while you're iterating through it.

Comment: @Prune gave beautiful answer, however, keep in your head, that writing one-liners is not *pythonic* way, and writing readable code is best practice! But now again, @Prune's answer is still readable enough, although you could import `from random import random` instead of `import random`, therefore you could use `random()` instead of `random.random()` to save space and increase redability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is viruses.remove(i). However, see the various postings on altering a list while you're iterating through it.

You can make this a one-liner; just call `random` for each virus, and include it if the "saving throw" works.

```
return [i for i in viruses if random.random() < mortalityProb]
```

For instance:

```
>>> viruses = [x for x in range(20)]
>>> [i for i in viruses if random.random() < 0.75]
[0, 1, 3, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 17, 18, 19]
```

BTW, you have your variable misnamed: `mortalityProb` should describe the chance of the organism dying, not surviving.

Answer (score 0):

Because in the for loop "i' is not actually the element in the list. You have to actually change the viruses list. Something like this may work.

```
def kill(viruses, mortalityProb):
    for x,i in enumerate(viruses):
        if random.randint(0, 100) < (mortalityProb * 100):
            viruses.pop(x)
    return viruses
```

Comment: You don't normally want to edit a list while you're iterating over said list. Can cause some weirdness if you're not careful.

Comment: That's true. I can never remember when its a problem and when its not.

Comment: It's typically always a problem unless you're using a stack/queue where you pop off the top to get the item. Popping modifies the object, but since you're only ever pulling from the top it's not a problem.

Comment: @SuperStew, if you can't remember when its a problem and when its not then you should probably find out and incorporate it into this answer or just remove this answer.

Comment: hmm it doesnt work... also what does viruses.pop(x) do exactly

Comment: the list shouldnt be edited expect from deleting the viruses that apply to that if statement

Comment: pop removes that element from the list and returns it's value.